# Media queries for website image

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have an issue with the media queries.
I have a website and I see it with Breakpoints Tester
 http://breakpointtester.com/

I have made the images with the width that the site sees them and now its the time for some css media queries.

```
<div class="bwpb-column bwpb-video-holder backgr vertical-col-align bwpb-colwidth-4 " style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); text-align: inherit; width: 100%; min-height: 611px; height: 375px; background: url(http://www.tfeditor.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/XXL-02.png) 50% 100% no-repeat rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div class="bwpb-overlay" style="background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.01)"></div><div class="bwpb-column-inner" style="padding: 0px 15px; margin-top: 305.5px;"></div></div>
```

I am trying to make this

```
http://jsfiddle.net/kwstasna/habpmjuw/
```

But the media queries are not working and when I use breakpoint again it shows only the same photo.

Can someone explain me why?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post your CSS so that we can see the issues you are dealing with

Comment: remove semi-clone from last of each media query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had semi-colons after the max-width properties that was breaking things.

Before:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1281px) and  (max-width:1600px;) {
```

After:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1281px) and  (max-width:1600px) {
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/habpmjuw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1281px) and (max-device-width : 1600px) { 

    // your css code 

    }
```

Comment: Can you explain what the differences are between the OP's code and yours, and why yours is better?

Comment: @Mr Lister, it will also work on devices(mobile and other).Device-width refers to the display's resolution (eg. the 1024 from 1024x768), while width refers to the width of the browser itself (which will be different from the resolution if the browser isn't maximized). If your resolution is large enough to get you in one break point, but the width of the browser is small enough to get you in another one, you'll end up with an odd combination of both.Please try with device also

Comment: I actually meant, edit your answer and add an explanation of what you did and why you did it.